# Как сделать так что бы при нажатие на контакта ,второе окно изменялось?

Tags: java, javafx

учусь делать простой мессенджер сообщений, вопрос - как это делается так ,что бы при нажатие на контакта ,второе окно изменялось для того , что бы там появился функционал для оправки сообщений, например как в Skype ,нажал на контакт и второе условное окно изменилось. Может списки контактов сделать кнопками или 2 сцены делать ?

Comment: Когда дочернее окно создаете, передаете туда ссылку на родительское окно. В дочернем окне через ссылку на родителя обращаетесь к нужному контролу или чему там у Вас

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: Я хочу , что бы нажимая на контакт Петров , правый фрейм приложения изменился , то есть в нем появились текстовое поле для отправки сообщения , кнопки и прочее .Как это делается ? мне нужно создать окно ,поделить как то его на 2 фрейма или сделать несколько сцен во общем беда.Тот же список контактов делать из кнопок и сделать им обработчик событий ?!. Работаю в javaFX Scene Builder . Буду благодарен за любой совет .